# 64GB+ memory card for Mobius action cam

Tags: video-camera, microsd, memory-card

I'm looking for MicroSD cards for my Mobius action cam. It's manual says the following:

> For the best compatibility use cards with a class 4 rating if
>   you have them. There is absolutely no advantage in using 
>   cards with a higher rating.

Despite of the manual above I have problems with a Kingston 64GB class 10 card (MBLY10G2/64GB or SDCX10/64GB) formatted by the camera to FAT32. (I was not able to find any SanDisk nor Kingston 64GB class 4 microSD card, class 10 is the minimum in this size.)

I use MOV file format, 1080p 30fps and super quality. Using MOV file format also means that the last second of the previous file is repeated at the beginning of the next file when the camera starts a new one.

Using Kingston SDCX10/64GB every file (except the first one) has a few bad frames between the 2nd and 10th seconds and there are 2-3 missing seconds in the video as well. [MPlayer on Linux](http://mplayerhq.hu/) (as well as VLC) prints lots of these errors while I'm playing the first 10 seconds:

```
Error while decoding frame!
[h264 @ 0x7fb839d08440]AVC: nal size -1790556904
[h264 @ 0x7fb839d08440]AVC: nal size -1790556904
[h264 @ 0x7fb839d08440]no frame!
```

I guess it's because of the one second overlap, the memory card could not cope with the double amount of data when switching files.

I'm afraid plain 64GB class 10 cards could be also too slow for this scenario. So I'm looking for a MicroSD card which 100% works with Mobius action cam, MOV file format, super quality, 1080p 30fps. (I would also appreciate experience with other cards which has the same issue as the Kingston one above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cards which are working perfectly:

- SanDisk Ultra 64GB
- Kingston microSD-XC 64GB UHS-I U1 GOLD Class10 SDCA10/64GB + adapter (90/45 MBps)

Another cards (although they are only 32GB ones) which also work well:

- Kingston microSD-HC card 32GB ULTRA Class10 SDCA10/32GB
- Samsung Memory 32GB Evo MicroSDHC UHS-I Grade 1 Class 10 Memory Card without Adapter